# La locution « à dormir debout » : pourquoi l'extravagant ou l'invraisemblable fait-il dormir de cette manière ?

Tags: prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, étymologie, locutions, origine-ou-raison

La locution [*à dormir debout*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_dormir_debout) est attestée en 1611 pour « extravagant » (DHLF/Rey) ; aujourd'hui ça signifierait surtout « invraisemblable ».

- Peut-on identifier la ou les premières attestations ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/debout) note
  Voltaire, près d'un siècle plus tard : « Les contes à dormir debout,
  dont vous me régalâtes l'année passée »,) et leur contexte et la
  qualité de la chose qui est *à dormir debout* ajoutent-ils des
  précisions au sens original (*extravagant*) ?
- Si l'on considère que des emplois comme *tenir debout* et
  éventuellement *ne pas tenir debout* etc. sont attestés plus tard
  (1617) que ceux avec *à dormir debout* (1611), a-t-on une idée de ce
  qui inspire cette locution, et que signifie exactement la référence au fait de *dormir debout* : pourquoi pas *courir allongé* par exemple ?

  - Peut-on analyser la préposition [*à*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) comme signifiant
    à l'origine la conséquence, « qui fait » (*dormir debout*) : pourquoi une histoire *à dormir debout* ferait-elle *dormir debout* ?

Answer (score 2):

***Dormir*** n'est pas uniquement employé pour dire que quelqu'un est dans l'état physiologique de sommeil. C'est aussi employé pour signifier « Demeurer inactif, inconscient, rêveur ou irrésolu, au lieu d'agir. » ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dormir)).
Il me semble que c'est de là qu'il faille partir pour justifier l'emploi du verbe *dormir* dans l'expression « dormir debout » et non pas en cherchant une juxtaposition de gestes et de positions apparemment invraisemblable. L'extravagance ne tient pas dans le fait que l'on dorme dans la position debout, ce qui est d'ailleurs physiologiquement possible (voir le somnambulisme).
Il faut prendre les deux mots dans leurs sens pleins : ce qui nous est raconté est tellement invraisemblable que ça ne m'intéresse pas, ça détruit en moi toute envie de réagir (je suis donc inactif), ça me laisse dubitatif (irrésolu).

Je ne trouve pas d'attestation plus ancienne que celle figurant dans le DHLF dont la date 1611 renvoie à la première publication du [dictionnaire de Cotgrave](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50509g.image) :

> [Ce sont des contes à dormir debout *These are most idle, frivolous, or foolish tales*.](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/cotgrave/dormir)

Si Cotgrave recense l'expression pour la faire figurer dans son dictionnaire il est vraisemblable qu'elle ait été en usage depuis un certain temps avant la date de publication.

L'emploi de la préposition *à* a bien une valeur causative : l'histoire est tellement invraisemblable qu'elle fait dormir quelqu'un sans qu'il ait besoin de se coucher.
Ce n'est pas la même valeur qu'on trouve dans les « [souliers à dormir debout](https://books.google.fr/books?id=-Yod0DCBFeUC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=oudin%20%22souliers%20%C3%A0%20dormir%20debout%22&source=bl&ots=9rWQ2YuGxL&sig=ACfU3U3JeuT7DrgKBDv-OOtZIRUoq0shsA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW-IKCucjkAhUDUhoKHWAcC8sQ6AEwAnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=oudin%20%22souliers%20%C3%A0%20dormir%20debout%22&f=false) »<sup>1</sup>, souliers dont la semelle est si large qu'elle permet à quelqu'un qui s'endort en étant debout de ne pas tomber, où la valeur du « à » est plutôt instrumentale.

---

<sup>1</sup>Cette expression a disparu de la langue aujourd'hui.

Comment: C'est une belle réponse, mais que je ressens incomplète car masquant peut-être un certain aspect de l'expression. Que faire, en effet, de la citation dans la question? *«Les contes à dormir debout, dont vous me régalâtes l'année passée»*. Il me semble que parfois, c’est l’accumulation d’événements et de coïncidences qui crée le sentiment d’invraisemblance, lequel ne serait pas obligatoirement désagréable, selon la citation... Les histoires du baron de Münchhausen, par exemple, conviendraient pour moi à ce type de passionnantes histoires à dormir debout.